# What are some common fixes for python's 'list index out of range' error?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm brand new to python and am attempting to create a program that takes a list of lists of nucleotide base sequences and performs a GC content check on each one. I'm receiving a 'list index out of range' error and am having trouble coming up with a good fix. Any feedback is greatly appreciated!

```
def test_gc(z):
    new_z = []
    for g in z:
        m = 0
        while m <= len(g):
            countC = 0
            countA = 0
            countG = 0
            countT = 0
            if g[m] == "C":
                countC = countC + 1
            elif g[m] == "A":
                countA = countA + 1
            elif g[m] == "G":
                countG = countG + 1
            else:
                countT = countT + 1
            m = m + 1

        gccontent = ((countG + countC) / (countG + countC + countA + countT)) * 100
        if gccontent < 60 and gccontent > 40:
            new_z.append(g)
        return new_z
```

Comment: `m <= len(g):` should be `m < len(g):`. But just use `for nucleotide in g:` and you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: you can also use the built-in `collections.Counter()` instead of writing your own code that counts each nucleotide.

Comment: lists in python are 0-index, that mean the first element have index 0 (`mylist[0]`) and the last one have index len(mylist)-1 (`mylist[len(mylist)-1]`) therefore your check should be `m < len(g)` as Barman mention. Beside that the [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is easy way to do it, alternatively if g is an string, list or tuple, those have a count method so you can also do for example `countG = g.count("G")`

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind editing your post and showing us the full traceback of the error?

Comment: Thank you all for the help! I implemented the collection counters, m < len(g), moved the counting variables, and shifted the return in order to make the function work. I appreciate all of your feedback, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
def test_gc(z):
new_z = []
for g in z:
    m = 0
    while m < len(g):
        countC = 0
        countA = 0
        countG = 0
        countT = 0
        if g[m] == "C":
            countC = countC + 1
        elif g[m] == "A":
            countA = countA + 1
        elif g[m] == "G":
            countG = countG + 1
        else:
            countT = countT + 1
        m = m + 1

    gccontent = ((countG + countC) / (countG + countC + countA + countT)) * 100
    if gccontent < 60 and gccontent > 40:
        new_z.append(g)
    return new_z
```

Instead of m <= len(g) use m < len(g). this error is because in programming arrray starts at 0

Comment: you mention the problem but you don't fix it in the sample code, oh and I just notice that there is an additional problem with the letters counter, you can take the chance and fix it too (they're constantly reset to 0)

Comment: Aha it is fixed now

Comment: cool, and what about the other issue I mentioned?

Comment: Thank you all for the help! I implemented your suggestions and moved the return statement and the program now works.